# Karma-Jasmine: Import Spy with noImplicitAny

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

If I set this in the `tsconfig.json` file of an Angular 4+ project:

```
"noImplicitAny": true,
```

...and import this to be used in a unit-test:

```
import { Spy } from "karma-jasmine";
```

...I am seeing this console error on `npm test`:

```
ERROR in C:/test-project/src/app/components/test/test.component.spec.ts (1,21):
Could not find a declaration file for module 'karma-jasmine'.
'C:/test-project/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/karma-jasmine` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'karma-jasmine';`
```

---

I tried this:

1. `npm install --save-dev @types/karma-jasmine`
2. Add `"types": [ "karma-jasmine" ]` to `tsconfig.json`

...and am now seeing this console error on `npm test`:

```
ERROR in C:/test-project/src/app/components/test/test.component.spec.ts (1,21):
File 'C:/test-project/node_modules/@types/karma-jasmine/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

---

How can I import `Spy` if `"noImplicitAny": true` is set?

If this is set to `false` (*which is the default value*), the import and usage works without error.

Example usage:

```
const testSpy: Spy = spyOn(testService, "test").and.callThrough();
```

Comment: Spy is part of the jasmine API. karma-jasmine integrates jasmine into karma. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jasmine/index.d.ts#L603

Comment: @JBNizet yes except importing Spy from "jasmine" fails with `[ts] Module '"jasmine"' has no exported member 'Spy'`.

Comment: You can just use `const foo: jasmine.Spy`. Or `import Spy = jasmine.Spy;` if you want to just use `const foo: Spy`.

Comment: AH I see, that's an easy fix :) Thanks @JBNizet, I would accept if this is your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the name of the framework is Jasmine. Karma is test runner that shouldn't be mentioned in specs, and `karma-jasmine` is Karma plugin to seamlessly run Jasmine specs.

Since `jasmine` is [a namespace](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/924fafffc09cfeb0267573af2c847cdbfcfa464d/types/jasmine/index.d.ts), it should be:

```
import * as jasmine from "jasmine";

const spy: jasmine.Spy = ...;
```

`jasmine` is supposed to be global, and `jasmine.Spy` can be used directly without `import`.

Comment: This results in the TypeScript compiler failing with `[ts] Module '"jasmine"' has no exported member 'Spy'`.

Comment: I updated the answer. Indeed, interfaces are often namespaced, this way it is clear that `Spy` belongs to `jasmine` and isn't a class.

Comment: Thanks @estus for the clarification, I am using `import Spy = jasmine.Spy;` instead but now I understand :)